# zip command in unix with wildcards

Tags: unix, zip

I am trying to zip file which is in the format of Amazon*.xls in unix and also remove the source file after compression.Below is the used command

```
zip -m Amazon`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`.zip Amazon*.xls
```

For the above command i am getting below error
zip I/O error: No such file or directory
zip error: Could not create output file Amazon.zip
PS: GZIP is working fine. I need zip format files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the zip, it is how your shell deals with expanding/substituting variables. Two lines solution for bash

```
export mydate=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
zip -m Amazon_$mydate.zip *matrix*
```

Execute by hand (few secs difference) or better put in a shell script myzipper.sh and just source it.

Answer (score 0):

Use '-p' instead of '-m', if zip files are to be extracted on Windows OS.

export mydate=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`

zip -p Amazon_$mydate.zip *matrix*